# Bring div to front in css

Tags: css

I have 2 section header and main(red one). i set *z-index* to 100 and want to bring main section to front but it goes to back i want to know what cause this in css?

```css
#red {
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
    <header style="background-color: black;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" />
    </header>

    <main id="red" role="main">        
      <div class="container">
          Red
      </div>
    </main>
```

[demo in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8hvxgu9/1/)

Comment: position:relative to red section

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this link about z-index:

> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

and note:

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).

```css
#red {
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
}



.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header style="background-color: black;">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" />
</header>

<main id="red" role="main">
  <div class="container">
      Red
  </div>
</main>
```

The easiest way however is to move the html higher in the hierarchy to move something on top. then you will have to style position on margins and size.